# Multi charts select like in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, multichoiceitems

I can create a single chart but I want to create multi charts that are selected all together when I hover over one of them, just like in google cloud dashboard : `console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard`

If you go to the dashboard there is Compute Engine and API chart, if I hover to Compute Engine chart in the specific time, the both charts are selected at that time.

Update
I found this one: 
http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/PRQkG/embedded/result,js,html,css/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle you provided to make the following fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/93scypa7/
```

1. You need to merge two configs.dataProvider into 1 using

   ```
   for (var i=0; i<arrayA.length && i<arrayB.length; i++){
       arrayC[i] = {date: arrayB[i].date, val1: arrayA[i].value, val2: arrayB[i].value};}
   ```

Hope this helps.

2. you need to add entry for each series under `config.graphs`.